# How to Authenticate while restoring a private package in github actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I'm attempting to restore a private package within the same organization on GitHub using GitHub Actions.

First, I created a Personal Access Token (PAT) with read-package permissions and added it to the repository secrets. Then, I used the following nuget.config file and script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/COMPANY/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="USERNAME" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="TOKEN" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

And this is the restore command  :

```
- name: 'Restore packages'
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      env:
       NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED: 0 # Disable token caching
       run: dotnet restore ${{ matrix.project_path }} --configfile nuget.config
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

I also attempted to work without the nuget.config file:

```
    - name: 'Add GitHub Package Registry Source'
      run: dotnet nuget add source ${{ env.GITHUB_PACKAGES_SOURCE_URL }} --name GitHubPackages -u "USERNAME" -p ${{ secrets.MYTOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text

    - name: 'Add NuGet.org Source'
      run: dotnet nuget add source ${{ env.NUGET_PACKAGES_SOURCE_URL }} --name NuGetOrg
   
    - name: 'Restore packages'
      run: dotnet restore ${{ matrix.project_path }}
```

In this case, I received an error indicating that the sources already exist, even though I deleted the nuget.config file.

I then attempted to delete the sources before adding them again :

```
- name: 'Clear Existing NuGet Sources'
          run: |
            $existingSources = dotnet nuget list source --format "Short"
            foreach ($source in $existingSources) {
            dotnet nuget remove source $source
            }
          shell: pwsh
```

But it still didn't work :

> error: Unable to find any package source(s) matching name: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/COMPANY/index.json.

Any solution or workaround ?